# How to unify sessions hosting a Facebook app built with Sinatra on Heroku

Tags: facebook, heroku, sinatra

I'm building a simple Facebook `Canvas` style app using `Sinatra`.

My app works fine when run locally on my own machine; but when I push it up to `Heroku` I get issues with Sessions not matching up and thus data placed into the session by /callback is not present when the page reload takes place.

The problem seems to be that when running on `Heroku`, it inserts some fancy load balancing and so that the `request.env['REMOTE_HOST']` is different between the page reload and the Facebook `callback` where the user's id is stored in the session.

Some (redacted) logging shows this clearly.

On Heroku (note the different remote hosts and thus different session IDs)

```
X9.1XX.XX1.XX - - [23/Aug/2012 03:27:42] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 1878 0.0235
DEBUG -- : ---------------------------------------------------------
DEBUG -- : ---------------------------------------------------------
DEBUG -- : Handling request from host ip-10-92-97-233.ec2.internal
DEBUG -- : Session ID: 39960b607fd7c1150791d4d42d6633b3b2a5b18e79e742f67d8f677f139dbca8
DEBUG -- : ---------------------------------------------------------
DEBUG -- : Set session['oauth'] : Koala::Facebook::OAuth
DEBUG -- : Session id: 39960b607fd7c1150791d4d42d6633b3b2a5b18e79e742f67d8f677f139dbca8
DEBUG -- : ---------------------------------------------------------
DEBUG -- : Session ID: 39960b607fd7c1150791d4d42d6633b3b2a5b18e79e742f67d8f677f139dbca8
DEBUG -- : Completed request from host ip-10-92-97-233.ec2.internal
DEBUG -- : ---------------------------------------------------------
DEBUG -- : ---------------------------------------------------------

X9.1XX.XX1.XX - - [23/Aug/2012 03:27:46] "GET /login HTTP/1.1" 302 - 0.0178
DEBUG -- : ---------------------------------------------------------
DEBUG -- : ---------------------------------------------------------
DEBUG -- : Handling request from host ip-10-94-82-253.ec2.internal
DEBUG -- : Session ID: 20200e42add5ec9bfe12b225502c7449dda6e8ab06dd3fbe204239db0e21de89
DEBUG -- : ---------------------------------------------------------
ERROR -- : Could not find oauth key in session 20200e42add5ec9bfe12b225502c7449dda6e8ab06dd3fbe204239db0e21de89
DEBUG -- : ---------------------------------------------------------
DEBUG -- : Session ID: 20200e42add5ec9bfe12b225502c7449dda6e8ab06dd3fbe204239db0e21de89
DEBUG -- : Completed request from host ip-10-94-82-253.ec2.internal
DEBUG -- : ---------------------------------------------------------
DEBUG -- : ---------------------------------------------------------

X9.1XX.XX1.XX - - [23/Aug/2012 03:27:48] "GET /callback?code=AQCs… …vxkEI76cq32juk HTTP/1.1" 302 - 0.0014
DEBUG -- : ---------------------------------------------------------
DEBUG -- : ---------------------------------------------------------
DEBUG -- : Handling request from host ip-10-125-37-231.ec2.internal
DEBUG -- : Session ID: a94f5f36b44e5891657982248d1304e265f9619bdcdc37b648879e5a12a0fe5b
DEBUG -- : ---------------------------------------------------------
DEBUG -- : ---------------------------------------------------------
DEBUG -- : Session ID: a94f5f36b44e5891657982248d1304e265f9619bdcdc37b648879e5a12a0fe5b
DEBUG -- : Completed request from host ip-10-125-37-231.ec2.internal
DEBUG -- : ---------------------------------------------------------
DEBUG -- : ---------------------------------------------------------
```

Locally (this works, note same host and matching session IDs)

```
X9.1XX.XX1.XX - - [23/Aug/2012 13:56:22] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 1878 0.0279
DEBUG -- : ---------------------------------------------------------
DEBUG -- : ---------------------------------------------------------
DEBUG -- : Handling request from host ppp12345.static.someprovider.net
DEBUG -- : Session ID: 892e6ec515afde6f463102f83d373523bba62b26180a2e5a34a4945c787eacfd
DEBUG -- : ---------------------------------------------------------
DEBUG -- : Set session['oauth'] : Koala::Facebook::OAuth
DEBUG -- : Session id: 892e6ec515afde6f463102f83d373523bba62b26180a2e5a34a4945c787eacfd
DEBUG -- : ---------------------------------------------------------
DEBUG -- : Session ID: 892e6ec515afde6f463102f83d373523bba62b26180a2e5a34a4945c787eacfd
DEBUG -- : Completed request from host ppp12345.static.someprovider.net
DEBUG -- : ---------------------------------------------------------
DEBUG -- : ---------------------------------------------------------

X9.1XX.XX1.XX - - [23/Aug/2012 13:56:31] "GET /login HTTP/1.1" 302 - 0.0079
DEBUG -- : ---------------------------------------------------------
DEBUG -- : ---------------------------------------------------------
DEBUG -- : Handling request from host ppp12345.static.someprovider.net
DEBUG -- : Session ID: 892e6ec515afde6f463102f83d373523bba62b26180a2e5a34a4945c787eacfd
DEBUG -- : ---------------------------------------------------------
DEBUG -- : ---------------------------------------------------------
DEBUG -- : Session ID: 892e6ec515afde6f463102f83d373523bba62b26180a2e5a34a4945c787eacfd
DEBUG -- : Completed request from host ppp12345.static.someprovider.net
DEBUG -- : ---------------------------------------------------------
DEBUG -- : ---------------------------------------------------------

X9.1XX.XX1.XX - - [23/Aug/2012 13:56:34] "GET /callback?code=AQCs… …vxkEshwXTPMC8lnaY9FU HTTP/1.1" 302 - 1.4674
DEBUG -- : ---------------------------------------------------------
DEBUG -- : ---------------------------------------------------------
DEBUG -- : Handling request from host ppp12345.static.someprovider.net
DEBUG -- : Session ID: 892e6ec515afde6f463102f83d373523bba62b26180a2e5a34a4945c787eacfd
DEBUG -- : ---------------------------------------------------------
DEBUG -- : {"username"=>"davesag", "verified"=>true, "updated_time"=>"2012-08-20T23:41:41+0000"}
DEBUG -- : ---------------------------------------------------------
DEBUG -- : Session ID: 892e6ec515afde6f463102f83d373523bba62b26180a2e5a34a4945c787eacfd
DEBUG -- : Completed request from host ppp12345.static.someprovider.net
DEBUG -- : ---------------------------------------------------------
DEBUG -- : ---------------------------------------------------------
```

So the question is, how do I tell Heroku to unify its sessions so that the cookies travel properly and match up?

Answer (score 0):

You should be using a session cookie to store the session id, instead of trying to dispatch based on REMOTE_HOST. REMOTE_HOST will be different based on heroku's routing, as you've seen, but will also be different if multiple people use the same outbound IP address.

Comment: I am using the session but the trouble is heroku is not returning the same session so anything i put in the session is lost.